# Flyway not connecting to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, flyway

I have a problem for a time and I yet have to find out why it is happening.

I'm trying to build a "instagram clone" to study Golang, but I cannot find out why my flyway does not connect to my postgresql.

Here is my docker compose:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: instagram
      POSTGRES_USER: instagram
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: instagram
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:9.9.0
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -c
      - flyway -defaultSchema=public -baselineOnMigrate=true -url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/instagram -user=instagram -password=instagram migrate
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./data/sql:/flyway/sql
```

The database seems to be correctly created, I can access it through DBeaver, however, my flyway cannot connect to it.

[image: ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/instagram) for user 'instagram': Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.]

I'm running it on a WSL2, I have already clear my docker deleting every container, volume and image from it once or twice. I'm running it with `docker compose up db` followed by `docker compose up flyway`.  Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: This is my docker compose file after the resolution for anyone that may need it

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
  db:
    image: postgres:14.5
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U instagram"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:9.9.0
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -c
      - flyway -defaultSchema=public -baselineOnMigrate=true -connectRetries=60 -url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/instagram -user=instagram -password=instagram migrate
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./data/sql:/flyway/sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes DB container takes a few seconds to spin up. Use `-connectRetries=60` flag in the command for automatic retries every second for x seconds. Check [GitHub Flyway docker](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker)

Using health check:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U instagram -d instagram -h db"]
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 10
```

Also, you can try to wait in an infinite loop in the command:

```
flyway:
  image: flyway/flyway:9.9.0
  command: ["sh", "-c", "while ! nc -z db 5432; do sleep 1; done; flyway -defaultSchema=public -baselineOnMigrate=true -url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/instagram -user=instagram -password=instagram migrate"]
  depends_on:
    - db
  healthcheck:
    test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U instagram -d instagram -h db"]
    interval: 5s
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 10
  volumes:
    - ./data/sql:/flyway/sql
```